# Laravel won't obey status code

Tags: php, json, laravel, http-status-codes

I just can't understand, and don't know where else to look, as the response status code of the following code is always 200, even if I set it to 400 in the main Response class.

```
class Api_Controller extends Base_Controller
{

    public function __construct()
    {
          parent::__construct();

          //header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found"); ##> This works
          //die();

          $test = array('1' => '2');
          die(Response::json($test, 400));
    }
```

What am I missing? I'm not using any extended class, just the default...

### Update

This is the output of the `Response::json...` above: http://pastebin.com/RGcinSdg

As you can see, the output has the values that has been set... but still for some reason, returns 200

### Update2

The output of `var_dump(http_response_code());` is always `200`

### Update3 - Temporary fix

I have activated an extended version of `Response::json` and add the following line to it

```
http_response_code($status);
```

But I would still much like to know why doesn't it does it, the way it should

Comment: maybe output is started before you want to set the status code.. but this should be easy to spot if you have error reporting on..

Comment: error reporting is on... I've updated the question with the output of `resonse::json`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't return responses from controller constructors - it just doesn't fit with the flow of the request lifecycle in Laravel.

There's two ways to do this. You can either:

a) Setup a response filter that handles whatever functionality it is you're trying to achieve or
b) Force a controller ACTION to return a response. This would be done like so:

```
class Api_Controller extends Base_Controller
{
    public $restful = true;

    public function get_index()
    {
        return Response::json($test, 400);
    }
}
```

It DOES work - you're just doing it incorrectly :)

Answer (score 3):

The same problem happens if you forget the **return** statement:

```
Response::json(array(
   'error' => true,
   'msg' => 'Bad request'
), 403);
```

instead of:

```
return Response::json(array(
   'error' => true,
   'msg' => 'Bad request'
), 403);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try the `response()->json()` syntax.

So, for example, to flag validation error from a custom FormResquest, you can do this:

```
/**
 * Get validation response for the request.
 *
 * @param  array $messages
 * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
 */
public function response(array $messages)
{
    return response()->json($messages, 422);
}
```

Comment: `\Response::json(...)` and `response()->json(...)` are the same thing; one uses a `Facade` while the other is a function. This does have merit for newer versions of Laravel though, as I think the `response()` function was introduced in Laravel 5.0 (or similar) and is referenced in the documentation over Facades.

Answer (score 0):

Controller methods always have to return responses. But I don't think you can return a response from the constructor. You would need to use a filter.

Answer (score 0):

To keep Google Webmaster Tools happy I detect and use the following in the header:

```
META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"
```