# Send custom 500 http response from Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I would like to send a custom http response with status as 500.
Tried the below code, but it's returning status as 200.

```
return response()
            ->json([
                'code'      =>  500,
                 'message'   =>  'custom error'
            ], 500);
```

How can I send http status 500 from laravel controller?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel - Return json along with http status code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31131159/laravel-return-json-along-with-http-status-code)

Comment: i think u missing something here (your code is working fine)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this.

```
return abort(500, 'custom error');
```

For more info:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/errors#http-exceptions

Hope this helps

**Update**

Try this then

```
return response()->json(['message' => 'error message'], 500);
```

That will send a 500 status code instead of a 200

For more info:

https://laravel.com/api/5.7/Illuminate/Contracts/Routing/ResponseFactory.html#method_json

Hope that helps.

Comment: AFAIK, `abort` actually renders a blade template, not JSON, would this work for the OP?

Comment: I believe you need to call `response` as a function: `return response()->...`