# When are the error: or success: handlers called in Ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

I had a code, where an `if` condition failed. In that case, I wanted the `error:` part of the Ajax to get triggered. But everytime, the `success:` of Ajax was called. Here is a code which can help you understand what I want to ask.

**Ajax request call**

```
success: function (response){
//some code 
},

error: function (response){
//some code
},
```

**In my backend code**

```
if(condition ){
//some code
return response()->json([
   'success'=>true,
   'message'=>"Success: handler in Ajax should be triggered"

]);
}else{
//some code
return response()->json([
   'success'=>false,
// OR 'error'=>true,
   'message'=>"Error: handler in Ajax should be triggered"

]);
}
```

But, even if the `condition` got `false`, the `success:` in Ajax was still triggered. It didn't go to the `error:` part. I didn't understand. Can someone explain what was happening?

Comment: Ajax doesn't know anything about your `success` *property* - that's not a standard HTTP response code.  In order to get to `error:` you need to fail in your back end and return a non-200 HTTP response code, eg a 500 error code.   Otherwise, in your `success:` callback, check for `response.success`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your success callback is beeing called, because the response was successfull since it returned the [HTTP status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes) of 200.

Your error callback is only called, when your controller action returns an status code of >= 400 .

If you modify your [controller action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31131272/174326) to:

```php
return response()->json(
  [
    'success'=>false,
    'message'=>"Error: handler in Ajax should be triggered"
  ], 
  400
);
```

Then your error callback will be called.

Comment: Can you tell me when can HTTP Status code return >=400? I am new to coding.

Comment: I attached a list with the description of every status code. But in simple words you could say that all status code begining with a 4xx are client errors and 5xx server errors.